# Running RISCV Rocket Chip Generator on Window 7

Tags: riscv

I am new to RISCV and not comfortable with linux. Can any body guide how can I build this rocket chip https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip using window platform only?

Comment: what  have you tried so far?

Comment: A quick glance tells me that most of this project uses Linux-only libraries and Linux-only utilities. You either need to use Linux or you need to use a Linux-emulator (like Cygwin) on Windows. Sounds like it's time to get comfortable with Linux.

Comment: I am using cygwin and getting following error in Building project riscv-fesvr:
../fesvr/elfloader.cc:75:56: error: ‘strnlen’ was not declared in this scope
         assert(strnlen(strtab + sym[i].st_name, max_len) < max_len); \
                                                        ^
../fesvr/elfloader.cc:84:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ELF’
     LOAD_ELF(Elf64_Ehdr, Elf64_Phdr, Elf64_Shdr, Elf64_Sym);
     ^
make: *** [Makefile:310: elfloader.o] Error 1

Comment: yea this code is not friendly to cygwin, is installing ubuntu in a vm an option? you will get much further with nearly the same amount of work this way

Comment: I am trying that to. I downloaded Virtualbox and installed ubuntu on it. But only the building of riscv tool is taking too much time. It has been almost around 7 hour since I gave build.sh command. It is still running but shows some warning msgs.